# Ozeki VoIP SDK catch the press event of phone

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I use Ozeki VoIP SDK LIBARY to connect SIP SYSTEM
and I have 2 questions :

1. Is there a way to convert text to Hebrew speech in c# or even in another language?
2. Do I have a way to know which user key is pressed?
   Thanks

Comment: For 1 there is a Microsoft Speech Synthesis API, yes, and the [list of supported voices](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/appendix-a-supported-languages-and-voices-4486e345-7730-53da-fcfe-55cc64300f01) includes Hebrew Asaf. [Speech synthesis documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/speech-technologies/jj572477(v=office.14)).

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer but I don't find a TTS download to Hebrew language

Comment: Settings, Speech Settings, Manage Voices, Add voices, Hebrew.